# How to make a 2d graph and replace values based on coordinates in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

I'm making a program which prompts the user for a linear equation and the range of x.

I want to output a 2d array which is full of dots, and depending on x and y, replace those coordinates with 0.
Here's my code so far:

```
lin_equation = input("Enter your linear equation in the format [a+b] where a is the coefficient and b is constant: ")
    ran_x = int(input("Enter the range of : "))+1
    coef = lin_equation.split('x')[0]
    print(f"Debug coefficient: {coef}")
    cons = lin_equation.split('+')[1]
    print(f"Debug constant: {cons}")
    graph = []
    graph_x = []
    max_x = int(ran_x)
    max_y = ran_x*int(coef)+int(cons)
    for i in range(1, max_y):
        for i in range(1, max_x+1):
            graph_x.append(1)
        graph.append([graph_x])
    
    for i in range(1, ran_x):
        y = i*int(coef)+int(cons)
        print(f"If  was {i},  would be: {y}")
        graph[i, y] = 0
```

I'm getting the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\farof\OneDrive\Desktop\linear equation calculator.txt", line 19, in 
graph[i, y] = 0
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How does that help me?